# помогите решить проблему с линейным списком

Tags: c++

Задание:Удвоить каждое вхождение элемента со значением Е в списке L.

Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;

struct list
{
    char data; //pole dannih
    int numb; //pole nomera elementa
    list *link;//pole adresa
};

list *sozdspis(char, int, list*);
list *addelem(char, char, list*);
void viewsp(list*);


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int i = 1;
    list *first = NULL;
    char ch, E;
    cout << "\n Вводите элементы списка сплошной строкой; "
        "\n в конце - точка: \n";
    cin >> ch;
    while (ch != '.')
    {
        first = sozdspis(ch, i, first);
        i++;
        cin >> ch;
    }

    cout << "Введите элемент E \n";
    cin >> E;

    first = addelem(E, ch, first);
    if (first != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Результат получен \n";
        viewsp(first);
    }
    else cout << "Результата нет\n";

    cin.get();
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}


list * addelem(char E, char ch, list *first)
{
    list *temp, *p, *now = first;

        while ((now != NULL) && (now->data)) 
        {
            now = now->link;
            if (now->data == E)         //все что я смог придумать D:
            {
                now->link = temp;
                temp->data = E;
                temp->link = now;
            }
        }
    return temp;
}

//viewsp Begin______________________________
//Просмотр циклического списка
void viewsp(list *head)
{
    list *tec = head;
    do
    {
        cout << tec->data;
        tec = tec->link;
    } while (tec != head);
}
//viewsp End___________________________________________________________________
//sozdspis Begin_______________________________________________________________
//Добавление нового элемента в список
list *sozdspis(char ch, int k, list *head)
{
    list *tec,
        *nov = new(list);
    nov->data = ch;
    nov->numb = k;
    nov->link = NULL;
    if (head) //список не пуст
    {
        tec = head;
        while (tec->link)
            tec = tec->link;
        tec->link = nov;
    }
    else //список пуст
        head = nov;
    return head;
}
```

Не могу понять как найти именно нужное число в списке

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;

    Node(int d) : data(d), next(nullptr) {};
};

class ForwardList
{
private:
    Node* _beg;
    Node* _end;
public:
    ForwardList() : _beg(nullptr), _end(nullptr) {};
    void push_back(int d);
    void doubleElement(int e);
};

void ForwardList::push_back(int d)
{
    Node* node = new Node(d);

    if(_beg == nullptr)
    {
        _beg = _end = node;
    }
    else
    {
        _end->next = node;
        _end = node;
    }
}

void ForwardList::doubleElement(int d)
{
    for(Node* it = _beg; it <= _end; ++it)
    {
        if(it->data == d)
        {
            it->data = (it->data) * 2;
        }
    }
}



int main()
{
    ForwardList list;
    list.push_back(3);
    list.push_back(9);
    list.push_back(1);
    list.push_back(2);
    list.push_back(4);
    list.push_back(100);
    list.push_back(2);
    list.push_back(5);

    list.doubleElement(100);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: хорошим стилем на so считается не только писать код, но и приводить пояснения.